# JQuery - How to select :odd immediate children of an element

Tags: jquery, select, element

I have a table as this:

```
<table class='table'>
<tr></tr>
<tr><tr>
<tr>
<table><tr></tr></table
<tr></tr>
</table>
```

and I want to select only the immediate odd tr after .table.

What I tried is:

```
$('.table > tr:odd').addClass('odd');
```

But it doesn't do the job.

Anyone knows? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and I want to select only the
>   immediate tr after .table.

You are using different class name than you mention, try:

```
 $('.table > tr:odd').addClass('odd');
```

---

Also make sure to wrap your code in ready handler:

```
$(function(){
     $('.table > tr:odd').addClass('odd');
});
```

---

You should also try adding `tbody`:

```
$('.table > tbody > tr:odd').addClass('odd');
```

Comment: Oop, I made the class 'table' up just for the question, but still it doesn't work. =/

Comment: @Mike, make sure to wrap your code in ready handler like i said in my answer.

Comment: Well, I searched firebug and this one works: $('.terminy_table tbody > tr:odd').addClass('odd'); but I don't have any 'tbody' element in my html, don't you know why it adds it?

Comment: @Mike: Yap certain browsers add/need it, you can try this selector: `$('.table > tbody > tr:odd').addClass('odd');` or `$('.table > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd)').addClass('odd');`

Comment: +1 sarfraz, came to same conclusion. Seems that browsers add the `tbody` on their own.. Works in IE7+, FF, Opera, Chrome, Safari (*demo at http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/3YEzY/*)

Comment: @Gaby: Yes problem comes out especially in IE.

Answer (score 1):

A different option will be to use the [`filter()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

```
$('.table > tbody > tr').filter(function(i){
    return !(i % 2);
}).addClass('odd');
```

This will enable you to use a valid CSS selector in your initial selection giving a good performance boost in browsers that support `querySelectorAll`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kbnH2/